# python lxml xpath get the nodes attributes with specific string pattern

Tags: python, xpath, python-requests, lxml, lxml.html

Im learning xpath and trying to get the value of node with specific node attribute for example(google playstore) using python lxml/html. From below code I wanted to get the developer email value from node "a" with attribute "href" starting with "mailto:". My python code snippet returns app name but empty developer email. Thank you

```
<html>
<div class="id-app-title" tabindex="0">Candy Crush Saga</div>
<div class="meta-info meta-info-wide"> 
<div class="title"> Developer </div> 
<a class="dev-link" href="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://candycrush.com" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"> Visit website </a>
<a class="dev-link" href="mailto:candycrush@kingping.com"
rel="nofollow" target="_blank">candycrush@kingping.com </a> ##Interesting part here
</div>
</html>
```

### Python code (2.7)

```
 def get_app_from_link(self,link):
    start_page=requests.get(link)
    #print start_page.text
    tree = html.fromstring(start_page.text)
    name = tree.xpath('//div[@class="id-app-title"]/text()')[0]
    #developer=tree.xpath('//div[@class="dev-link"]//*/div/@href')
    developer=tree.xpath('//div[contains(@href,"mailto") and @class="dev-link"]/text()')
    print name,developer
    return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you are using tag `div`, not `a`:

`'//a[contains(@href,"mailto") and @class="dev-link"]/text()'`

Also, your function don't return items. Use `return` like:

```
def get_app_from_link(self,link)::
    # your code
    return name, developer
```